# Hidden server is not reachable on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: onion-services, configuration, raspberry-pi

I'm having difficulty getting my hidden service working correctly. I have worked on many apache systems before but for some reason I can't get this one working. I have followed all the steps [here](http://nfokjgfj3hxs4nwu.onion/) and installed raspbian. Everything compiles correctly and installs just fine. No errors or anything but when all is said and done (port forwarding included) my onion address is unreachable. I have tried changing the port to 80 instead of what I had it as (8080) but that also didn't work. Only once did I get it to show an error 500 page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I should also mention that both the access log and regular log show no errors or problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The guide makes Apache run as  system user `debian-tor`:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=debian-tor
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=debian-tor
```

but the permissions on `/var/www` doesn't get set to `debian-tor` as well so probably it's a permission problem.

BUT BESIDES THAT:

1. You shouldn't follow that guide. He configures the `HiddenServiceDir` to be `/var/www` which is also document root for Apache. And make Apache run as `debian-tor`. The `HiddenServiceDir` has nothing to do with Apache. It holds information about the Hidden Service. Someone could try to get the `private_key` file and hijack your Hidden Service address. Not sure if creator of that guide just don't know what he does (lack of information) or if it's stupidity or pure intention. At least his setup differs from that described in his guide.
2. Apache has a lot of stuff which could reveal information, you should use nginx or lighttpd if you don't know how to secure Apache.